# Get child nodes from an object

Tags: jquery, json

I have an object with some dynamic keys. I'm able to read the key name, but not the value:

```
var response = {
    "keyOne": {
        "keyChanged": {
            "keyTwo": {
                "keyINeed": "myData"
            }
        }
    }
}

var myKey = Object.keys(response.keyOne)[0];
var myValue = response.keyOne."something".keyTwo.keyINeed
```

How can I do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To achieve this you need to use bracket notation, as you're providing the key of the object in a variable. Try this:

```js
var response = {
  "keyOne": {
    "keyChanged": {
      "keyTwo": {
        "keyINeed": "myData"
      }
    }
  }
}


var myKey = Object.keys(response.keyOne)[0];
var myValue = response.keyOne[myKey].keyTwo.keyINeed; // note the [] here

console.log(myKey)
console.log(myValue);
```